# Storage issue doubt

Tags: internal-storage, sd-card, storage, link2sd

My phone is micromax canvas magnus Android 4.2.1
Here are two pictures from the settings app... 
Why the storage shown for Apps(app data and media content)  is different from the info i get after opening it...

Then the storage used by apps is almost half.

Please tell us there a big in my phone or does this Halen with everyone

P. S i don't have any media files on my internal card... It is only and only for Apps !

After tapping into it says around 350mb other wise in the previous outer menu it says near to 536 mb

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzxE4.png) 
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSwfa.png)

Answer (score 0):

One is the physical storage the apps themselves take up, and the other is the space the apps AND the app data and media content take up.  Apps will create folders as needed to cache/store things they may need to access, etc.